# default value when checkbox is not clicked

Tags: android, checkbox

I am writing an app where the selection of output depends on the checkbox selected. I have 4 checkboxes for choosing different filters.

```
private  String  x=null;

public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {

    CheckBox check1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_OK);
    CheckBox check2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_NOK);
    CheckBox check3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_CHECK);
    CheckBox check4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_ALLOK);
    if (check1.isChecked()) {
        x = "0000";
        Log.d(TAG, x);
    } else if (check2.isChecked()) {
        x = "1111";
        Log.d(TAG, x);
    } else if (check3.isChecked()) {
        x = "8888";
        Log.d(TAG, x);
    } else if (check4.isChecked()) {
        x = "";
        Log.d(TAG, x);
    }
else{x=""; }
}
```

How do I put a default value if none of the checkboxes are clicked? I tried initialising the String x which passes the filter value but the app crashes when I try to display the results without any checkbox being checked.

Comment: Try this private String x = "";

Comment: can you please post your activity whole code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1:
Initialize String with default value

```
String x = "myDefaultValue";
```

Option 2: Using else, if no checkbox isChecked, then you get into the else

```
if (check1.isChecked()) {
    x = "0000";
    Log.d(TAG, x);
} else if (check2.isChecked()) {
    x = "1111";
    Log.d(TAG, x);
} else if (check3.isChecked()) {
    x = "8888";
    Log.d(TAG, x);
} else if (check4.isChecked()) {
    x = "";
    Log.d(TAG, x);
} else{
    x = "default value";
    Log.d(TAG, x);
}
```

The error you got is a NullPointerExeption because you initialise your String with null. Using one of the two options will fix the problem.

Comment: its good to describe what you have changed and why the error happened.another answer is change `String  x=null;` to `String  x="";`

Answer (score 1):

> How do I put a default value if none of the checkboxes are clicked

Initialize the variable with the default value

```
x = "default_value";

if (check1.isChecked()) {
    x = "0000";
    Log.d(TAG, x);
} else if (check2.isChecked()) {
    x = "1111";
    Log.d(TAG, x);
} else if (check3.isChecked()) {
    x = "8888";
    Log.d(TAG, x);
} else if (check4.isChecked()) {
    x = "";
    Log.d(TAG, x);
}
```

Comment: In Xml, you can declare as android:checked="true" for any one of the checkboxes. It is a simple fix and it will looks as a default checkbox selection!